# JavaFX drop shadow gets cut off

Tags: java, css, javafx, dropshadow

I am working on a project for school and we are required to use JavaFX to create a desktop application.
I am mainly responsible for how the application looks but I am still running in some problems.

One of these problems occures when I apply a drop shadow to one of my components.
The drop shadow is there but it gets cut off because my component is inside another Pane.

As you can see in this image, the drop shadow is visible but it still gets cut off on the right side.

[image: screenshot of drop shadow cut off]

If it helps, this is my fxml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>
<?import java.lang.String?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="be.hogent.sdp2_g14.ui.EmployeesViewController"
            stylesheets="@../css/global.css">

    <top>
        <fx:include source="header.fxml"/>
    </top>
    <center>
        <HBox styleClass="bg-white">
            <Pane HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS"/>
            <AnchorPane>
                <VBox prefWidth="817" prefHeight="200" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14" AnchorPane.topAnchor="14" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="14" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="14">
                    <!--Title area-->
                    <HBox alignment="CENTER">
                        <Label styleClass="page-title">Employees</Label>
                        <Pane HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS"/>
                        <HBox spacing="14" alignment="CENTER">
                            <Label text="Sort by:"/>
                            <ComboBox fx:id="comboBoxSort" prefWidth="150.0" styleClass="combo-box" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="14.0" >
                                <items>
                                    <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                                        <String fx:value="A - Z" />
                                        <String fx:value="Z - A" />
                                    </FXCollections>
                                </items>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </HBox>
                    </HBox>
                    <!--Searchbar area-->
                    <HBox spacing="14" styleClass="py-md-sm">
                        <TextField fx:id="searchBar" styleClass="input-field, drop-shadow" onKeyPressed="#handleOnKeyReleased" promptText="Search by name..." HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                        <Button  fx:id="createEmployeeButton" onMouseClicked="#handleCreateButtonClicked" prefWidth="150" styleClass="primary-button" text="CREATE +"/>
                    </HBox>

                    <!--Page content-->
                    <ScrollPane fitToWidth="true" styleClass="bg-transparent" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                        <GridPane fx:id="gridPaneEmployees" styleClass="bg-white" hgap="10" vgap="10" prefWidth="817.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                    </ScrollPane>
                </VBox>
            </AnchorPane>
            <Pane HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS"/>
        </HBox>
    </center>

</BorderPane>
```

This is my global.css file that I am using for this fxml file.

```
* {
    /*TODO: Change to inter*/
    -fx-font-family: 'Arial';
}

.page-title {
    -fx-font-size: 40;
}

.cursor-hand {
    -fx-cursor: hand;
}


/*CARD*/

.card-base {
    /*-fx-border-color: #535858;*/
    /*-fx-border-width: 1;*/
    /*-fx-border-style: solid;*/
    -fx-background-radius: 6;
    /*-fx-padding: 10;*/
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-padding: 14 10 14 10;
}

.card-text {
    -fx-font-size: 24;
}

.card-subtext {
    -fx-font-size: 20;
    -fx-text-fill: #D9D9D9;
}

/*CONTROL*/

.primary-button {
    -fx-background-color: #EF463C;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-cursor: hand;
    -fx-padding: 10 14 10 14;
    -fx-font-size: 14;
}

.primary-button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #ea6d66;
}

.secondary-button {
    -fx-background-color: #D4D4D4;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-cursor: hand;
    -fx-padding: 10 14 10 14;
    -fx-font-size: 14;
}

.secondary-button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.input-field {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-padding: 10 14 10 14;
    -fx-font-size: 14;
}

/*CONTROL (Automatic)*/

.combo-box {
    -fx-cursor: hand;
    -fx-background-color: #d3d3d3;
}

/*SPACING*/

.pt-sm {
    -fx-padding: 14 0 0 0;
}
.pt-md {
    -fx-padding: 24 0 0 0;
}

.pl-sm {
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 14;
}
.pl-md {
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 24;
}

.py-md-md {
    -fx-padding: 24 0 24 0;
}

.py-sm-sm {
    -fx-padding: 14 0 14 0;
}

.py-md-sm {
    -fx-padding: 24 0 14 0;
}

.py-sm-md {
    -fx-padding: 14 0 24 0;
}

/*SCROLLBAR (Automatic)*/

.scroll-bar {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-pref-width: 0;
}

.scroll-pane {
    -fx-background: white;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.increment-button, .decrement-button {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
}

.scroll-bar .thumb {
    -fx-background-radius: 5em;
}




.text-bold {
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

.text-24 {
    -fx-font-size: 24;
}

.text-20 {
    -fx-font-size: 20;
}

.bg-white {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}

.bg-transparent {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.bg-error {
    -fx-background-color: #EF463C;
}

.debug-red {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}


.debug-green {
    -fx-background-color: green;
}


.debug-blue {
    -fx-background-color: blue;
}


/*Effects*/
.drop-shadow {
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, rgba(211, 211, 211, 5), 10, 0, 2, 2)
}
```

If you happen to have a solution, please let me know!

I tried setting the root pane's background to transparent but that still didn't fix it.

Comment: No, I don't see any problem with drop shadows. Every field has a drop-shadow. (a) Edit your Question to more precisely state the problem. (b) When posting here, reduce your code to an absolute *minimum* needed to show the issue.

Comment: @BasilBourque I’m guessing Creatos is talking about the Jane Doe and John Doe buttons on the right side of the window.  Those buttons’ bottom drop shadows are visible, but the drop shadow on the right side of each button is clipped.

Comment: “If it helps, this is my fxml.”  No, it does not help, because the buttons which are being clipped are not in that .fxml file, and I’m not sure if `gridPaneEmployees` is the parent node of those buttons.  Edit your question and show the code which adds the buttons to the scene.

Comment: You can place a node in a group to include the effect area in its layout bounds (will also make the node not resizable), or you can add the appropriate amount of padding to the node.